# Create data frame from multiple lists of same length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list like this,

```
l1=[1,2,3,4,5]
l2=[6,7,8,9,10]
l3=[11,12,13,14,15]
l4=[16,17,18,19,20]
```

Now I want to create a data frame from above list where l1, l2, l3, l4 will be rows, and the elements of those rows will be column values, so the final data frame will look like,

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
  1       2       3       4       5
  6       7       8       9       10
  11      12      13      14      15
  16      17      18      19      20
```

I could do this using for loop in every list and element wise selection to each column but the execution time will be more, looking for some pandas shortcuts to do it more efficiently

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> l1=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> l2=[6,7,8,9,10]
>>> l3=[11,12,13,14,15]
>>> l4=[16,17,18,19,20]
>>> data = [l1,l2,l3,l4]
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=[f'col_{i}' for i in range(1, len(data)+2)])
>>> df
   col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4  col_5
0      1      2      3      4      5
1      6      7      8      9     10
2     11     12     13     14     15
3     16     17     18     19     20
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how:

```
import pandas as pd

l1=[1,2,3,4,5]
l2=[6,7,8,9,10]
l3=[11,12,13,14,15]
l4=[16,17,18,19,20]

d = {'col1':l1,'col2':l2,'col3':l3,'col4':l4}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
 col1  col2  col3  col4
    1     6    11    16
    2     7    12    17
    3     8    13    18
    4     9    14    19
    5    10    15    20
```